# Webpack 5 and css-loader aren't compiling @value directive from CSS Modules

Tags: webpack, sass, css-modules, css-loader, postcss-loader

We have a React app with Webpack 5. There are some `.scss` files that are importing values from a component library installed in `node_modules` using the `@value` directive from CSS Modules. Everything was working great until `css-loader` version 3, but we upgraded `css-loader` to the last version (6.7.1) and now those values aren't compiled in the final code. Before we got the actual value for those variables (a hexadecimal color value) and now we get the name of the variable with some kind of prefix and suffix.

Before we got:

```css
.my-class {
  background: #5efa0b;
}
```

for `@value brightGreen: #5efa0b;` in a `color.css` file that was imported in `.scss` file. And now we get:

```css
.my-class {
  background: i__const_brightGreen_135;
}
```

The `.scss` files are like:

```
@value brightGreen from '~@MyComponentsLibrary/src/Styles/colors.css'

.my-class {
  color: brightGreen;
}
```

and `colors.css` is something like:

```
@value brightGreen: #5efa0b;
@value brightBlue: #4664ec 

//more colors
```

The actual Webpack configuration is this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const packageJson = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: ['whatwg-fetch', '@babel/polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
    depVersions: './src/depVersions'
  },
  resolve: {
    // allows importing without file extension for these
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js'), 'node_modules'],
    fallback: {
      'os': require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
      'buffer': require.resolve('buffer')
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals: {
    '@MyComponentsLibrary': 'components-library',
    'react': 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  'postcss-modules-values'
                ]
              },
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        type: 'asset',
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 10000
          }
        },
        generator: {
          dataUrl: {
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, 
        type: 'asset'
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, 
        type: 'asset',
        parser: {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 8192 // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'),
        'npm_package_name': JSON.stringify(packageJson.name),
        'npm_package_version': JSON.stringify(packageJson.version)
      }
    }),
  ]
}
```

And these are the versions of the relevant packages installed.

```
    "my-components-library": "2.2.0",
    "css-loader": "6.7.1",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.3",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.4.3",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-modules-values": "^4.0.0",
    "webworkify-webpack": "^2.1.5",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
```

I have very little experience with Webpack so maybe (for sure) I'm missing something. I read the documentation for Webpack, css-loader and postcss-modules-values, but I couldn't find an answer. I also tried two things:

1. Remove the `~` character from the first line of the `.scss` files, which didn't work.
2. If I declare the value in the `.scss` file where it is used, it works... If I have a `.scss` file like this the value is compiled:

```css
@value brightGreen: #5efa0b;

.my-class {
  color: brightGreen;
}
```

but the idea is to be able to use the values from our components library.

I really appreciate any help you can provide. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@value` directive is a CSS module feature. I know that `css-loader` will by default only apply the CSS module specification to files ending in `.module.css` ([source](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#modules)). Can you try renaming `colors.css` to `colors.module.css` or updating `css-loader` or `postcss-loader` configs to consider all `.css` files as modules (this option will decrease performance)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for the delay. What you are saying makes sense and gave me something to think about. And I finally could find the solution: I had to add to css-loader the option: `modules: {   mode: 'global' }`, with that I could remove postcss and the postcss-loader and changed the value for `importLoaders` to `1`. 
And now all the colors are correct :)
Thanks again!